# QML 5.3 iOS compilation of pure QML app

Tags: ios, qt, qml

I have an application written in QML.  Initially, I used the standard C++ bootstrap for the app.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    // A bunch of components and data models written in C++
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
    return app.exec();
}
```

The bulk of the app is in QML and the more I work with QML, the happier I am with it and the more I feel comfortable converting the C++ pieces to QML.  So, it comes to one risk that I wanted to ask about.

If I convert the app to a pure QML application like the kind generated by the Qt Quick UI application wizard with no C++ and designed to be run with **qmlscene** will I be able to compile it for iOS when the time to port it comes or will I end up just converting it back to the C++ loader form?

### TL;DR

Can pure QML (no C++) apps be compiled and run on iOS devices?

Comment: QML apps are not compiled!

Comment: @FinalContest I was trying to find the right word.  Deployed maybe?  The process of getting the app on the device. Packaged?

Comment: Yes, that is called deploying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is not currently possible for iOS (or Android). I know from experience on Android that it's not supported. For example, see [this](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-30879?focusedCommentId=224873&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-224873) comment. You can't really go wrong sticking to the default application template Creator sets up for you.

Comment: I think that you are correct.  I'll keep this open for a day and see if there are any other comments.

Comment: @NathanielJohnson: I would suggest to open a ticket on Qt's Jira.